# wordpress custom html widget with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add a php code inside a custom HTML widget but the site in showing this like plain text.

Any idea why is this happening?

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
$param = uniqid();
echo "<script language='javascript'>";
echo "alert('message successfully sent ' . $param)";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

**HTML:**

[image]

**HOW I SEE THE PAGE:**

[image]

Comment: Wordpress' Custom HTML widget doesn't support PHP. You would need to install a plugin for that functionality, ie [PHP Code Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/)

Comment: since it's a simple JS code, why not simply put it without PHP tag

Comment: its simple js only for the example.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem happenned to me today!!, resolved it by adding the following code to the Wordpress theme function.php file.

```
add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
function execute_php($html){
     if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
          ob_start();
          eval("?".">".$html);
          $html=ob_get_contents();
          ob_end_clean();
     }
     return $html;
}
```

To enable shortcodes in the Text and Custom HTML widget just add this code to your theme functions.php :

```
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode',10);
```